# Recebendo id errado

Tags: java, mqtt

No pequeno projeto que tô fazendo, o usuário insere seu login e senha. O sistema faz um POST para uma URL e checa a resposta. Se logar, retorna algumas coisas como o ID do usuário, o email e tudo mais.

Eu preciso pegar o ID do usuário para poder me inscrever num tópico MQTT, porém tô com problemas para pegar esse ID! Já consegui mapear e separar do JSON, mas quando tento usar ele tô recebendo sempre zero. Vou postar as classes abaixo (pelo menos as partes pertinentes).

Classe responsavel por fazer o post (quando chamada):

```
public class SenderPost {
    private HttpResponse response;

    public int getIdReceived() {
        return idReceived;
    }

    private void setIdReceived(int idReceived) {
        this.idReceived = idReceived;
    }

    private int idReceived;

    int postLogin(String login, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

       //(código omitido) configurações do POST

        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entidade = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entidade, "UTF-8");
            DOMInfoLogin dil = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, DOMInfoLogin.class); // aqui eu mapeio o JSON pra poder usar os atributos
            setIdReceived(dil.getId()); //aqui eu coloco o atributo idReceived como o id que recebo do JSON

      }
       //(código omitido) tratativas de erro 

        return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Essa é a classe que executa a SenderLogin e confere a resposta dela (para ver se logou, e se não logou, o por que):

```
public class AutenticaLogin {

    public SenderPost post = new SenderPost();

    boolean autenticaLogin(TextField txtID, PasswordField pwdField, Button btnLogin) throws IOException {
        btnLogin.setDisable(false);
        switch (post.postLogin(txtID.getText(), pwdField.getText())) {
            case 200:
                return true;
//(código omitido) Tratativas para outros status code
        }
    }
}
```

Por fim, o método onde está o erro efetivo (esse método fica em outra classe, mas vou omitir ela e deixar só o método): Eu tento concatenar minha String com a informação e ai recebo isso. (Antes de usar o método set, eu recebia NPE)

```
 private AutenticaLogin auth = new AutenticaLogin();

    public void connect() throws MqttException, IOException {
    //(código omitido) Configurações do MQTT
    String topic = "topico/"+auth.post.getIdReceived()+"/start";
//(código omitido) Conexões do MQTT
}
```

E aqui no debug está o problema, mas não sei como resolver
(era pra receber 195)
[image: Debug do projeto]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi criar atributo e método set estático, e quando recebo o ID, atribuo na classe. Não sei se é o ideal, mas funciona bem para o que preciso.

```
private static String getIdReceived() {
    return idReceived;
}
switch (post.postLogin(txtID.getText(), pwdField.getText())) {
            case 200:
                MqttBase.setIdReceived(post.getIDClient());
                MqttBase.setEmpresaReceived(post.getIDEmpresa());
                return true;
//código omitido
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você chamar o método `autenticationLogin` para alimentar sua variável `idReceived` da classe `SenderPost`

```
 private AutenticaLogin auth = new AutenticaLogin();

    public void connect() throws MqttException, IOException {
    //(código omitido) Configurações do MQTT

    auth.autenticaLogin(txtID, pwdField, btnLogin);

    String topic = "topico/"+auth.post.getIdReceived()+"/start";
//(código omitido) Conexões do MQTT
}
```

Se você não chamar o `autenticationLogin` você nunca vai chamar o `postLogin`, que por sua vez irá alimentar a variável `idReceived`.

Comment: Certo, mas aí eu teria que fazer a autenticação já no método de conexão do MQTT, não é? A ideia era que ele só tentaria conectar no MQTT se logasse. Esse método (autenticaLogin) é que faz pega os dados digitados pra enviar por POST e tudo mais...

Comment: Minha área não é muito Java, desculpe se eu estiver falando besteiras... Mas pela lógica suas variáveis estão vindo como `NULL` porque não estão sendo alimentadas, só são alimentadas quando executado o método `autenticaLogin`, então se só vai dar o POST se logar no MQTT tu precisa ver alguma forma de alimenta-las.

Comment: Sim, é isso que está acontecendo. Acho que ainda não consegui entender a forma correta de se fazer, se existe algo especifico que pode me ajudar. Obrigado pela tentativa, vamos ver se mais alguém aparece...

Comment: De nada, logo alguém que entenda bem vem como uma solução!